# Google Sheets REGEXEXTRACT splits into two cells

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have cell B10 with text that contains slashes and I want to extract the text around those slashes.

Example: Text in B10 is `PV AA/BB 1250/2500/13` and I want to extract `1250/2500` in cell O10.

I tried to do `=REGEXEXTRACT(B10, "([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\/([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])")` but for some reason, this splits the result into two cells (O10 and O11), without the /. Similar happens when I try to extract the `AA/BB` with `([a-zA-Z]+)\/([a-zA-Z]+)` - it returns `AA` and `BB` in two separate cells.

What is happening here? How do I extract the string into one cell only, with the slash?

Answer (score 1):

you have extra brackets "()" in your regular expression it should be,

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B10, "([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\/[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])")
```

the brackets ")(" before and after / is removed to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B10; "\d{4}.\d{4}")
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B10; " (\d+.\d+)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can 2 capture groups, but for a match you don't need any groups, and the `/` also does not have to be escaped.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B10, "[1-9]\d{3}/[1-9]\d{3}")
```

[image]

---

Or use `REGEXREPLACE` with the 2 capture groups and the `/` in the replacement and matching all chars before and after it so that they won't be present after the replacement.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B10, ".*([1-9]\d{3})/([1-9]\d{3}).*", "$1/$2")
```

[image]